# Filtering Firebase Firestore document's array of maps

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a field named cartons in a document which is an array of maps.

```
**each document in a collection 
**document-1
    { lotNo: 'alg-100', 
      cartons:[
              {cartonNo:01, trackingNo:'a'},
              {cartonNo:02, trackingNo:'b'},
              {cartonNo:03, trackingNo:'c'},
              {cartonNo:04, trackingNo:'a'}
             ]
    }

**document-2
    { lotNo: 'alg-101', 
      cartons:[
              {cartonNo:01, trackingNo:'a'},
              {cartonNo:02, trackingNo:'b'},
              {cartonNo:03, trackingNo:'c'},
              {cartonNo:04, trackingNo:'a'}
             ]
     }
```

what I need is only the carton object where trackingNo='a' from each document. As far I know I can't get partial data from a firestore document(either get the full document on not). So to get the carton object of similar trackingNo from different documents I am assuming get both of the documents then filter the data in client-side. Or is there any better way? what could be the best possible solution for achieving only the carton that has a similar trackingNo(as an array) from different documents ( without changing the data structure as my app is heavily relying on this particular data structure)?

Comment: Can you clarify your expected results? What exactly do you want to get back from Firestore? If you were to do a query on what's shown for trackingNo = 'a', then document-1 and document-2 would be returned. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you can't index based on properties inside of an array. In the Realtime Database, properties of an array could be indexed as `cartons.<index>.trackingNo` (e.g. `cartons.0.trackingNo`), but if you queried this, you would only get documents that contain the requested tracking number as their first carton entry. To get all results, you would need to query again for each subsequent index - `cartons.1.trackingNo`, `cartons.2.trackingNo`, and so on.

If the data is as simple as you have shown, the best option would be to tweak your data structure slightly so that you also store a list of tracking numbers in the given lot. This will allow you to perform [`array-contains` queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership) on a `trackingNos` property.

```
{
  lotNo: 'alg-101', 
  cartons: [
    { cartonNo: 01, trackingNo: 'a' },
    { cartonNo: 02, trackingNo: 'b' },
    { cartonNo: 03, trackingNo: 'c' },
    { cartonNo: 04, trackingNo: 'a' }
  ],
  trackingNos: [
    'a',
    'b',
    'c'
  ]
}
```

If your data has been simplified to be posted here, you might be better off with a restructure of your database where each carton is a member of the lot document's subcollection called cartons (i.e. `.../lots/alg-101/cartons/01`) and combined with a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query).